# How to communicate with modem over Ethernet?

Tags: ip, modem

I have an old modem I was considering repurposing. The first step I thought to do was connect my computer with the modem and try to map the open ports. I found that, upon connecting the device, that my `eth0` interface was assigned an IP address. My computer also has a wireless NIC (`wlan0`), so I now have two IP addresses.

I scanned `eth0` and got the results. Then, for good measure, I port mapped my wireless interface only to find that the results were identical. As such, the obvious conclusion is that by scanning `eth0` I was in fact scanning myself.

So, how can I go about scanning the modem? My knowledge in this space is limited, but in order to do this I imagine the modem itself requires the assignment of an IP. Or am I thinking about this incorrectly?

**EDIT**: The modem is an older Motorola 3360 used ages ago with a DSL connection.

Comment: What kind of [modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem) do you have? (it does not mean much; my latest optical-fiber internet connection also has a modem and gives me 200 Mbits/sec).... Why and what for do you want to use it? How is your modem connected (physically & logically)? To what? With what protocols ([PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol)....)? Please **edit your question to improve it**; it is currently nearly meaningless.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Repurpose in terms of throwing away its "modem" functionality and using any available I/O pins and processing power for something completely different.

Comment: Please edit your question, instead of commenting it. Give more details about your modem (e.g. hardware reference, how it is connected, etc.) And explain why you consider doing that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, All I know of the modem is the model information. A search around Google gives only user manuals with no technical references that I could find.

Comment: But why do you want to reuse it (especially since it has apparently bad reputation)? Does it have *several* ethernet ports? Can't you just buy a cheap Ethernet bridge or hub?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I've seen this done before on various types of hardware that has outlived its usefulness. I am not trying to make this thing useful as a modem again. Check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VY9SBPo1Oy8) video at around `27:30`